How do I get multiple data-attributes from a single option select assigned to different javascript variables?
I am trying to assign 2 different javascript variable values from multiple data-attributions in a dropdown menu.  One value is working just fine, the other keeps returning null.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Example of an option line from html form:
<select onchange="calculateNPF()" id="yourCamera" name="yourCamera" class="form-control">

<option value="79" data-sensor-width="36" data-sensor-height="24" data-cropFactor="1" data-pixelPitch="6.6" data-resolution="20.1">Canon EOS R6</option>

let yourCameraPixelSize = document.getElementById('yourCamera');
let pixelSize = yourCameraPixelSize.getAttribute('data-pixelPitch');
let yourCameraSensorSize = document.getElementById('yourCamera');
let sensorSize = yourCameraSensorSize.getAttribute('data-cropFactor');

In the above code "pixelSize" is working properly whereas sensorSize returns null

We'll need to see the relevant html to help you.

I don't see how either of those properties are being read, given that the option you've shown doesn't have any of the id values you're targeting. As @mykaf says, can you please show all relevant HTML

You haven't shown any element with id="yourCamera". The option you've shown doesn't have an id at all. Please update the question with more context. Is the id="yourCamera" element the select? When do you need to do this? (For instance: in an event handler?) Do you need it for the selected element? [Which seems likely.])

(Separately: There's no reason to get the same element twice, and you might want to look at the dataset property. For instance, you might be able to do const { pixelPitch, cropFactor } = document.getElementById("yourCamera").selectedOptions[0].dataset; but again, we need more context.)

I just added more info to the HTML; apologies for the miss

Just as a style note, it's very common to use - names like data-pixel-pitch and data-crop-factor in the HTML markup. When you access the data attributes via the .dataset property on the DOM element objects, you can use the camel-case names ("pixelPitch", "cropFactor"). I suggest avoiding .getAttribute() and using .dataset instead.

You're trying to get the attribute values from the select element, but they're on the option element.
If you're trying to get these attribute values from the selected option (or options), you can use the selectedOptions collection for that. Since it's a single-select, you'd just want .selectedOptions[0] for the first (only) one. Here's an example:


function calculateNPF() {
    const yourCamera = document.getElementById("yourCamera");
    const selectedOption = yourCamera.selectedOptions[0];
    if (!selectedOption) {
        return;
    }
    const yourCameraPixelSize = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-pixelPitch');
    const yourCameraSensorSize = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-cropFactor');
    console.log(`yourCameraPixelSize = ${yourCameraPixelSize}`);
    console.log(`yourCameraSensorSize = ${yourCameraSensorSize}`);
}
<select onchange="calculateNPF()" id="yourCamera" name="yourCamera" class="form-control">
  <option>Choose an option</option>
  <option value="79" data-sensor-width="36" data-sensor-height="24" data-cropFactor="1" data-pixelPitch="6.6" data-resolution="20.1">Canon EOS R6</option>
</select>



I should note that the name yourCameraSensorSize doesn't really match the attribute name data-cropFactor though.

FWIW, I suggest avoiding onxyz-attribute-style event handlers and using addEventListener instead. You could also use the dataset property if you like. Here that is with your original attribute and variable names:


const yourCamera = document.getElementById("yourCamera");
yourCamera.addEventListener("change", calculateNPF);
function calculateNPF() {
    const selectedOption = yourCamera.selectedOptions[0];
    if (!selectedOption) {
        return;
    }
    const {
        pixelpitch: yourCameraPixelSize,
        cropfactor: yourCameraSensorSize
    } = selectedOption.dataset;
    console.log(`yourCameraPixelSize = ${yourCameraPixelSize}`);
    console.log(`yourCameraSensorSize = ${yourCameraSensorSize}`);
}
<select id="yourCamera" name="yourCamera" class="form-control">
  <option>Choose an option</option>
  <option value="79" data-sensor-width="36" data-sensor-height="24" data-cropFactor="1" data-pixelPitch="6.6" data-resolution="20.1">Canon EOS R6</option>
</select>



